# Quarkus RestClient from MavenLocal issue

Tags: maven, quarkus

I have two folders, one containing my api interfaces and the other containing the implementation of my services. I want to use my RestClient in my BFF service, so I've publishedToMavenLocal my users-api project containing my user api interface and RestClient. Then I injected my UserClient into my BFF service. The problem is that I get the following error when starting the service :

```
error]: Build step io.quarkus.arc.deployment.ArcProcessor#validate threw an exception: jakarta.enterprise.inject.spi.DeploymentException: jakarta.enterprise.inject.UnsatisfiedResolutionException: Unsatisfied dependency for type org.acme.client.UserClient and qualifiers [@RestClient]
    - java member: org.acme.resource.UserResource#userClient
    - declared on CLASS bean [types=[java.lang.Object, org.acme.resource.UserResource], qualifiers=[@Default, @Any], target=org.acme.resource.UserResource]
    at io.quarkus.arc.processor.BeanDeployment.processErrors(BeanDeployment.java:1453)
    at io.quarkus.arc.processor.BeanDeployment.init(BeanDeployment.java:311)
    at io.quarkus.arc.processor.BeanProcessor.initialize(BeanProcessor.java:160)
    at io.quarkus.arc.deployment.ArcProcessor.validate(ArcProcessor.java:472)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.ExtensionLoader$3.execute(ExtensionLoader.java:849)
    at io.quarkus.builder.BuildContext.run(BuildContext.java:256)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextHandler$1.runWith(ContextHandler.java:18)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2513)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1538)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:501)
Caused by: jakarta.enterprise.inject.UnsatisfiedResolutionException: Unsatisfied dependency for type org.acme.client.UserClient and qualifiers [@RestClient]
    - java member: org.acme.resource.UserResource#userClient
    - declared on CLASS bean [types=[java.lang.Object, org.acme.resource.UserResource], qualifiers=[@Default, @Any], target=org.acme.resource.UserResource]
    at io.quarkus.arc.processor.Beans.resolveInjectionPoint(Beans.java:478)
    at io.quarkus.arc.processor.BeanInfo.init(BeanInfo.java:624)
    at io.quarkus.arc.processor.BeanDeployment.init(BeanDeployment.java:299)
    ... 11 more
```

I think the problem comes from publishing in maven local, it seems that my application.yaml is not taken into account and so my RestClient has no url.
(I added: **implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-config-yaml'** in my **build.gradle**)
I've tried recreating my UserClient inside my bff service and it works.
Here's my simple configuration:
UserClient :

```java
@Path("/users")
@RegisterRestClient(configKey = "users-api")
public interface UserClient {

    @GET
    List<UserDto> list();

    @GET
    @Path("/{id}")
    UserDto get(UUID id);

    @POST
    UserDto create(UserDto userDto);

    @PUT
    @Path("/{id}")
    UserDto update(UUID id, UserDto userDto);

    @DELETE
    @Path("/{id}")
    void delete(UUID id);
}
```

UserResource:

```java
@Path("/users")
public class UserResource {

    @RestClient
    UserClient userClient;

    @Inject
    UserMapper userMapper;

    @GET
    public List<UserResponse> list() {
        List<UserDto> users = userClient.list();
        return userMapper.toUserResponses(users);
    }
}
```

application.yaml :

```yaml
quarkus:
  rest-client:
    users-api:
      url: http://localhost:8082 #user service URL
```

(I tried to add: scope: `jakarta.inject.Singleton` but didn't work...)

Comment: Please also add `org.acme.resource.UserResource` source to the question.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I added **UserResource**